# Error operación inválida en C#

Tags: c#

Ultimamente mi aplicación me muestra siempre el mismo error y no se como solucionarlo.
El error es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente depurar mi programa pero sigo sin saber donde esta el error.

el codigo del programa:

```
internal void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //metroProgress.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
```

Comment: tienes que poner tu código. Así no podemos ayudarte.

Comment: Cuando te salga este mensaje de error, dale click en `Copiar detalles de la escepción en el portapapeles`, luego **[edit] tu pregunta**. Además, encierra tu código en un bloque `try/catch`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lees bien fijiate que dice:

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'metroProgress' accessed
>   from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Español:

> La operación de subprocesos no es válida: Control 'metroProgress' se
>   accede desde un hilo que no sea el subproceso en el que se creó.

Solo puedes modificar un control dentro del hilo de la vista
Lo mas seguro es que estas creando un hilo al inicio de la aplicacion y en ese hilo estas modificando el control `metroProgress` dentro del hilo:

Ejemplo:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>{
   metroProgress.Visibility = Visibilty.Hidden; // invalido, solo en el hilo de la vista puedes modificiarlo
})
```

Asi que para solucionarlo debes de utilizar el metodo [`Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx) que se ejecuta en el hilo de la vista:

```
 Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>{
       metroProgress.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { metroProgess.Visiblity = Visibility.Hidden; }));

    });
```

**Actualizacion:**

En tu caso seria:

```
internal void ProgressChanged(object sender, 

DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    metroProgres.Invoke(new Action(() => {
       metroProgres.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }));

}
```

Comment: puse el código. la excepcion me sigue lanzando.

Comment: Utiliza el Invoke` del control `metroProgress`, no del control padre:  `metroProgress.Invoke(()=>{ metroProgress.Value  = e.ProgressPercentage; })`

Comment: intente con esto Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { metroProgres.Value = e.ProgressPercentage; }); intente con invoke pero me pone no puede convertir lambda en tipo delegate.

Comment: Mira la respuesta actualizada

Comment: sigue siendo el mismo error. creo que el error es en esta linea web.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(Program.load.ProgressChanged); actualizare el post con el codigo adicional.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y publica el codigo relevante e indicanos donde te lanza el error.

Comment: esta solucionado gracias. las respuestas son las correctas

Comment: Me alegra sabe eso. Recuerda marcar la respuesta que te funciono como aceptada.

Answer (score 0):

Sería bueno ver el código, pero por lo que puedo deducir, estás intentando acceder alguna propiedad de un control (metroProgress) desde un hilo diferente al que fue creado, esto no es posible hacerlo directamente por que vas a recibir ese error que estas viendo, en cambio puedes intentar usar :

```
metroProgress.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
    metroProgress.Value = newValue;
}));
```

Value seria la propiedad que quieres cambiar y newValue, el valor que le quieres asignar a dicha propiedad.

Comment: puse el codigo igual pero sigue dandome esa excepcion